# Main types of contrast involved in contrastive analysis of syntax?

Tags: syntax

What are the main types of contrast involved in contrastive analysis of syntax? I would appreciate a few examples.

I tried to find an answer, but unfortunately I found nothing.

Comment: Welcome! I don't know the answer, but I'm sure someone else will.

Comment: what is meant by contrastive analysis? perhaps it is on analogy to structuralist analysis in morphology/phonology?

Answer (score 1):

The function of contrastive analysis is to predict linguistic issues learners might face as they acquire a second language. It has two areas, intralingual and cross lingual.

If it is intralingual, you might:

- analyse contrastive phonemes/neutralisation.
- analyse the lexical relations.
- analyse morphemes (bound or unbound)that carry grammatical meaning.
- look at features of the languages morphosyntactic categories - the relationship between morphology and syntax, or in lay terms 'grammar'.
- look at word order.

If it is crosslingual, you might also:

- compare lexical semantics, basically 'meaning'.
- study translational equivalence